# Url.Action and culture in ASP.Net core

Tags: asp.net-core

On my bilingual site (English & Spanish) developed using ASP.Net Core 3.1, I have 2 distinct views (staff and program) populated by their own controller/viewmodels which contains the exact same links:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Detail", "Staff", new { nodeAlias= "JohnDoe" })' class="...">TEST STAFF</a>
<a href='@Url.Action("Detail", "Program", new { nodeAlias="group1"})' class="...">TEST PROGRAM</a>
```

These links are associated with routes such as the following:

```
     endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "ProgramDetail",
            pattern: "{culture}/Research/Program/{nodeAlias}",
            defaults: new { action = "Detail", controller = "Program", culture = DefaultCulture, nodeAlias = "default", nodeParent = "Research" },
            constraints: new { culture = new SiteCultureConstraint() }
        );
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "AboutStaff",
                pattern: "{culture}/About/Staff/{action}/{nodeAlias?}",
                defaults: new { action = "Index", controller = "Staff", culture = DefaultCulture, nodeParent = "About" },
                constraints: new { culture = new SiteCultureConstraint(), nodeAlias = new AlphaRouteConstraint() }
            );
```

The default culture is English and it works file in this language.

However, I am having issues when I switch to Spanish.
For example, In Spanish, when I am on the program page, the program link is correctly built (eg.:`/es/Research/program/group1`) while the link is wrong for the staff page (`en/About/Staff/Detail/johnDoe`).
But if I switch to the staff page which contains the exact same links, i get the wrong culture for the program link (`/en/Research/program/group1`) but the good one for the staff page (`es/About/Staff/Detail/johnDoe`).

It looks like the pattern is that links generated by url.action are using the current culture only on the pages from the matching controller/viewmodel/context.

It is quite unclear to me if it is normal and why I have this behaviour.
Anyone could explain it to me and how to solve it?

Thank you,

S.

Comment: By using the `Url.Action`, how do you add the culture to the url? I check it on my side, it will show the request url without culture. Besides, you could try to directly set the href attribute without using the `Url.Action`, like this: `<a href='en/About/Staff/Detail/johnDoe' class="...">TEST STAFF</a>`. When the user changes the culture, use JQuery to change the hyperlink href attribute's culture.